# I want to disable a button when day and time are >= universal time

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

i do an application in ASPX that need to stop updating on buton click event in a esplicit time and date, i need to disable the button when response redirect to the page i need if time is reach button on the page apears disable

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
Dim d as New DateTime(2017, 8, 7) 'year, month, day

If DateTime.UtcNow > d Then 'if current time is greater than d
    button.Enabled = False
End If
```

DateTime documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326680(v=vs.71).aspx
DateTime.UtcNow documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Thanks, but i  need the universal time metod or how can i set up the time with hours?

Comment: Create whatever date time your limit is using the DateTime constructor, I edited my code to be DateTime.UtcNow (Current Universal Time) instead of Now.

Comment: Use ToUniversalTime() Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx